# Make a new dataframe by filtering multiple columns(list or base.Index) pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed that there are a lot of questions about this topic.
Until now I found something kinda close for what I need:

```
newdf = df[df[df.columns].isin(['list','of','values'])]
```

But this method deletes all the values that are not in df.columns keeping the same df.shape

What I need is something like this:

```
newdf = df[df[df.columns[1:]].isin(['val1','val3','val7'])] 


 df                      newdf                       
 col1  col2   col3       col1  col2  col3
 A     val1   val5       A     val1  val5 
 B     val2   val2       C     val3  val3
 C     val3   val3       D     val4  val7
 D     val4   val7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUIC, you need `any`

```
In [252]: df[df[df.columns[1:]].isin(['val1','val3','val7']).any(1)]
Out[252]:
  col1  col2  col3
0    A  val1  val5
2    C  val3  val3
3    D  val4  val7
```